# Microsoft Windows Performance Recorder dropped events during a boot trace

Tags: windows, performance

Does anyone know how to increase the number of buffers associated with the Microsoft Windows Performance Recorder application?  I was trying to capture a boot trace and got the following error message when opening the .etl trace file with Windows Performance Analyzer:

=== Begin error message ===

Performance Analyzer noticed that 1782066 events and 0 buffers were lost in this trace.

This is usually caused by insufficient disk bandwidth for ETW logging.

Please try increasing the minimum and maximum number of buffers and/or the buffer size.  Doubling these values would be a good first attempt.

Please note, though, that this action increases the amount of memory reserved for ETW buffers, increasing memory pressure on your scenario.

See “xperf –help start” for the associated command line options.

Windows Performance Analyzer might not be able to provide reliable data in this situation.

Would you like to continue analyzing this trace?

=== End error message ===

Comment: this often happens when the disk is extremely slow. does the disk graph in WPA show a high activity?

Comment: Yes the disk utilization is high because I am trying to capture a boot trace for Windows 7 because the boot time is taking longer than expected.

Comment: simple solution, buy a SSD, this will fix (nearly) all boot perf issues.